# Save events and time of its occuring in a plist iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiresponder, uievent

I have a UIViewcontroller with different UI elements in it. I would like to get a way to track the events occuring on that view ,its point of occurence,and the time of the event occuring without doing any hardcoding to save it on the corresponding actions.Also the process should not disrupt the occuring events.I would like to save that details into a plist.Can anybody tell me how to acheive this? Any constructive suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging on that part I found the solution to my issue in the following link.
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/automated-user-interface-testing-on.html
Hope that helps somebody out there looking for solution for the same. However applications using the provided solution will be rejected by appstore. It can be used only for your own purposes.